# Adding large 3d models into Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, graphics, models, blender

I have a 3d model of a restraunt with several characters in it probably over a hundred objects. Whenever I try to import it into Unity Unity just loads forever until I force close it. How do you import such large models without Unity crashing?

Comment: It`s 1 large mesh or many separated meshes? Can you edit your post with vertex  count?

Comment: Is there a reason you need them in one single mesh? Why not break them down into multiple smaller models?

Answer (score 1):

Verify how many polygons your models have. High poly objects need more time and processor to load in scene. On Blender you can see the number of polygons on the top-right when in Edit Mode, and in Youtube you can see how to decrease the number of polygons with Blender. An other possible solution is import the model in parts. As I can see, you want to import a restaurant with a lot of models together. Divide and conquer. Try to separate the itens and import them separately.